# PHP SOAP using nested parameters

Tags: php, xml, soap

Please see example code. I need to pass the parameters to the following SOAP server. Problem is the security and the login code are nested and not direct parameters. I am currently using the SoapClient PHP object.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some example code to call this function with all optional parameters even if you in the example simply use any dummy name, id number, login name etc.

```
POST /TPNWebServices/CreditCheck/consumer.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: test.tpn.co.za
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tpn.co.za/ConsumerIDVerification"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConsumerIDVerification xmlns="http://tpn.co.za/">
      <SecurityBlock>
        <SecurityCode>string</SecurityCode>
        <AuthToken>string</AuthToken>
        <OutputFormat>string</OutputFormat>
        <LoginCode>string</LoginCode>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <SessionId>string</SessionId>
      </SecurityBlock>
      <RsaIdNumber>string</RsaIdNumber>
      <FirstName>string</FirstName>
      <Surname>string</Surname>
    </ConsumerIDVerification>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i have understood the question correctly, hope this works:

```
    $client = new SoapClient($urlWSDL);
    $client->consumerIDVerification([
        SecurityBlock => [
            SecurityCode => 'xxx',,
            AuthToken => 'xxx',
            OutputFormat => 'xxx',
            LoginCode => 'xxx',
            Password => 'xxx',
            SessionId => 'xxx',
        ],
        RsaIdNumber => 'xxx',
        FirstName => 'xxx',
        Surname => 'xxx',
]);
```

I don't know the function name of the service you are calling replace it in **consumerIDVerification**

---